# Attribute error even though code works. Does it matter?

Tags: javascript, python, attributeerror, event-stream

I'm calling a function attribute to update a variable in a while loop within my Flask app, to then send data in a Response to my template JS to update css attributes - this is to update a progress bar in PyTube.

I receive 'AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'percentage of completion'within Powershell.

My code works and does it's job.

Although I want to follow best practices and write proper code, in this instance it's a work around as I am unable to find any other solution.

Being new to Python and Flask, i'd like to know does this error matter and if so, what negative impact will it have?

**Function**

```
def on_progress(stream, chunk, bytes_remaining):
    total_size = stream.filesize
    bytes_downloaded = total_size - bytes_remaining
    on_progress.percentage_of_completion = bytes_downloaded / total_size * 100
```

**Route containing while loop**

```
@app.route('/progress')
def progress():
    def generate():

        x = 0

        while x <= 100:
            x = round(on_progress.percentage_of_completion)
            yield "data:" + str(x) + "\n\n"
            time.sleep(0.1)



    return Response(generate(), mimetype= 'text/event-stream')
```

**Template JS**

```
var source = new EventSource("/progress");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
    $('.progress-bar').css('width', event.data+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', event.data);
    $('.progress-bar-label').text(event.data+'%');

    if(event.data == 100){
        source.close()
    }
}
```

**Template CSS**

```
<div class="progress" style="width: 50%; margin: 50px;">
     <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">
                <span class="progress-bar-label">0%</span>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're getting is straightforward. The `on_progress` entity is a function, and has no `percentage_of_completion` attribute.

What you probably want to do is to change your function so that it **returns** the percentage of completion :

```py
def on_progress(stream, chunk, bytes_remaining):
    total_size = stream.filesize
    bytes_downloaded = total_size - bytes_remaining
    
    return bytes_downloaded / total_size * 100
```

And then use it properly, as a function call:

```py
...
    while x <= 100:
        x = round(on_progress())
...
```

Note that I haven't read the rest of your code, you might have some additional issues that I haven't taken into account.

Comment: Thanks for your input here.

My on_progress function is a callback function which takes 3 arguments, however these arguments are passed over via the PyTube package (I believe), therefore I receive...

'missing 3 required positional arguments: 'stream', 'chunk', and 'bytes_remaining'.


I'm slightly out my comfort zone when explaining things with the proper terminology, so I hope I got that right and it makes sense.

Still open to resolutions on this!